# Removing enclosing [ ] in bash strings

Tags: bash

I have bash strings enclosed by `[]`, e.g. [name], [surname].  And want to remove the starting `[` and closing `]`.  What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
$ echo "$var"
[name]
```

then either

1. using a string slice (removes the first and last characters - regardless of what characters they are)

   ```
   $ echo "${var:1: -1}"
   name
   ```
2. using pattern substitution (globally removes `]` and `[` regardless of where they occur in the string)

   ```
   $ echo "${var//[][]/}"
   name
   ```